# Converter double para string mantendo o mesmo formato

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Eu preciso converter uma valor do tipo `double` para `string` em C#, sem que esse valor seja alterado para notação científica.

o meu código é:

```
double valor1 = 0.000024746578864525161;

string resultado = Convert.toString(valor1);
```

a minha saída fica: **2,8192381923E-15**

eu queria que a saída fosse exatamente a mesma mais em *string*

saída : **"0.000024746578864525161";**

as razões pelas quais eu preciso que o valor **não** seja expresso em notação científica são:

1 - Eu estou lendo um XLSX.

2 - Estou fazendo a validação dos valores inseridos pelo usuário. E nessa validação, não posso permitir caracteres inválidos.

3 - Minha string é submetida a um Regex.

```
Regex(@"[;!*#&@?()'$~^<>ºª%\{}A-Za-z]");
```

4 - O Fato do meu Regex não aceitar caracteres faz com que o número expresso em notação **2,8192381923E-15** torne-se inválido.

Existe uma forma de fazer a conversão de:

```
 double varlor = 0.000024746578864525161;
```

para

```
string resultado = "0.000024746578864525161"
```

e não para notação científica:

```
string resultado = "2,8192381923E-15"
```

Comment: Quais são os caracteres inválidos? Talvez precise mudar o seu pensamento e a lógica do que está tentando fazer!

Comment: os caracteres inválidos estão no Regex

Comment: Não qur editar isso aí pra mostrar a sua saída real em notação científica? O nḿero que voce põe no exemplo de saída não é o mesmo que está na variável "valor1"

Comment: @Mik3i4a5 A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível fazer exatamente assim, mas algo próximo, pode formar assim:

```
valor1.ToString("#########0.000000000000000000000000")
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/FormatZeros.cs).

Vai notar que não pega todos os dígitos possíveis, não importa quantas casas coloca. O tipo `double` tem exatidão limitada. Se quer mais exatidão deveria usar um `decimal`. Pode por 339 casas, sei lá porque fazer isto, e não terá resultado mais exato. Faça o teste e verá que vai até o `0.0000247465788645252`.

Se quer precisão maior aí deve abrir mão da exatidão e a notação científica é adequada.

O Excel trabalha bem com notação científica. Se não é isso que deseja, o problema parece ser outro.

Não confunda o número com representação numérica. Quando converte para *string* está abandonando o número e pegando a sua representação, que são coisas diferentes.

Claro, pode fazer uma conversão manual, mas dá bastante trabalho e não é fácil fazer certo.

Talvez queria fazer outra coisa, mas não temos como saber pela pergunta. Se o conceito estiver errado qualquer resposta técnica será ruim.